# How to only get rid of the refresh widget once reload is fully done

Tags: android, kotlin

In my app, I added a swipe down reload in kotlin, and It works. When you swipe down, it shows the refresh widget and then goes back up and starts to refresh the page. But it takes my app a few seconds to refresh since It's refreshing a website. Does somebody know how to only make the refresh widget go back up once the refresh is done?

Here's my code:

MainActivity.kt:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val FINE_LOCATION_RQ = 101
    val CAMERA_RQ = 102
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        refreshApp()
        webViewSetup()
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private fun webViewSetup() {
        val wb_webView = findViewById<View>(R.id.wb_webView) as WebView
        wb_webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        wb_webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        wb_webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        wb_webView.loadUrl("https://google.com/")
    }

    private fun refreshApp() {
        val webView = findViewById<View>(R.id.wb_webView) as WebView
        val swipeToRefresh = findViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(R.id.swipeToRefresh)
        swipeToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
            webView.loadUrl( "javascript:window.location.reload( true )" )
            swipeToRefresh.isRefreshing = false
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val wb_webView = findViewById<View>(R.id.wb_webView) as WebView
        if (wb_webView.canGoBack()) {
            wb_webView.goBack()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeToRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/wb_webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Does somebody know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can override the onPageFinished in the WebClient like,

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
            swipeToRefresh.isRefreshing = false
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed :D